# Sorting taking case into consideration

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code

```
    function asc(a, b) {
        return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text());
    }
```

When I pass a,d,c,e,b I get the correct values a,b,c,d,e

However when I pass a,d,C,e,b I get C,a,b,d,e

How can I make the code work when a different Case is used?

Comment: Take a took at an ASCII table and that should give you some clues as to why this is happening.  You can 'correct' the behaviour by lower (or upper) casing the values before you compare them...

Comment: It's unclear if you are looking for a case insensitive sort, if you want the upper-case variant to come after the lower-case variant, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If** you're looking for a case-insensitive sort, the easiest way is to convert both sides to all-upper or all-lower case.

```
// Note: Not for Array#sort
function asc(a, b) {
    return $(b).text().toLowerCase() < $(a).text().toLowerCase();
}
```

Note, thought, that I'm assuming you're **not** using this with `Array#sort`, as it doesn't do what `Array#sort` expects (return `0`, `<0`, or `>0`).

---

Side note: The `()` around `$(b).text()` and `$(a).text()` in your quoted code have no effect whatsoever, I've removed them above.

---

From your comment:

> if I have to sequence the 'C' after 'c' in the example, how will i do it?

Ah, now that's different. This works for `Array#sort`, you'll have to modify it to match however you're using `asc` (I don't know what you expect to do in the case where strings match): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/IXilAqEG/1)

```
// Note: Designed for Array#sort, may need modifying
function asc(a, b) {
    var btext = $(b).text(),
        atext = $(a).text(),
        blc,
        alc;

    if (atext === btext) {
        // Same
        return 0;
    }
    alc = atext.toLowerCase();
    blc = btext.toLowerCase();
    if (alc === blc) {
        // Case-insensitive match, compare case-sensitive and
        // ensure uppercase comes after lowercase.
        return atext < btext ? 1 : -1;
    }

    // Different even ignoring case
    return alc < blc ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Shall I use toLocaleLowerCase() instead of toLowerCase() incase someone uses non-english letters?

Comment: Also what If I have to do a Case-sensitive sort?

Comment: @TomHodder: Using the locale version may make sense. Re your question question above, the version you already have *is* a case-sensitive sort.

Comment: It's unclear if he wants `a, a, A, b, B, c, C` or if `a, A, a, B, b, c, C` is acceptable.

Comment: @crush: Agreed, that was me upvoting your earlier comment. :-)

Comment: No I meant that if I have to sequence the 'C' after 'c' in the example, how will i do it?

Comment: @TomHodder: Ah, that's different. But before answering it, how are you using `asc`? Because what's in your question is not appropriate for use with `Array#sort`, for instance.

Comment: @TomHodder So you want upper case letter to come directly after their lower case variant? e. g. `"Camel", "crisis", "call"` would be sorted as `"call", "crisis", "Camel"` Is that correct?

Comment: @TomHodder: I've added a version that does that with `Array#sort`. You'll have to modify it for whatever you're using your current function with, as `asc` doesn't do what `Array#sort` expects.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment "Note, thought, that I'm assuming you're not using this with Array#sort" Which sort method am I using then and how is it different from Array#sort? Sorry but I am missing the point here, so please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: @TomHodder What he meant was that the callback function that is passed to `Array.sort` needs to return either `0, 1, or -1`. 0 means that the element stays where it is. 1 means that it increases position, and -1 means it decreases position within the array. However, your `asc()` function was returning a boolean value, which would get implicitly cast to either `0` or `1`, and never `-1`.

Comment: @TomHodder: What crush said (but it doesn't *have* to be `1` or `-1`, the return values `Array#sort` expects are `0` if the items are the same, any positive number of `a` is greater than `b`, and any negative number if `a` is less than `b`).

Comment: Ok so something that can be achieved using $.makeArray() too right?

Comment: I mean JavaScript built-in sort() function is used on this array, which does an in-place sort of the array?

Comment: @TomHodder: I think you're not getting the point: The `asc` function in your question cannot be used with `Array#sort`. It doesn't do what `Array#sort` expects the function you give to it to do, which is return `0`, `<0`, or `>0`. Your function returns `true` or `false`. If your goal is to use this function with `Array#sort`, the second version I added to the answer works with `Array#sort`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The .sort() that I have used in my code, does it have a documentation anywhere on the web?

Comment: @TomHodder Please see the documentation found on Mozilla's Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @TomHodder: Of course it does, not least in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11)! But the MDN link crush gave above is more readable.